# REGEX, trying to target item BEFORE match term

Tags: regex

I'm writing a script to go through a bunch of email alerts for a backup system.

I need to target the server name.

I've already written a script that can parse through my outlook.

The expected input is:

> Server-DC  Error   1:04:34 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Incremental copy was not processed during the copy interval
>
> Server-DC2 Error   1:05:30 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     A server caught on fire
>
> ABCDEFG    Error   1:06:26 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Someone cried into the powersupply and now the server is offline
>
> EXCH2019   Error   1:07:29 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Backup failed because it felt like it
>
> SBS2003ISBAD   Error   1:08:40 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Backup failed because someone thought backup software was malicious
>
> ANCIENT-DB Error   1:09:49 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Windows forced an update during backup window
>
> FILESERVER Error   1:10:54 AM  1:00:13 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     I'm running out of ideas to anonymize this data
>
> VM4EVRYTING    Error   1:12:11 AM  1:00:13 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Why are you still reading these
>
> WEBSERVER  Error   1:13:19 AM  1:00:13 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     I get hundreds of these a day I'm only showing you 9

I need to target the server name, which is ALWAYS before "Error"

I've got:

```
(?sm)Error(?<servername>.*?)$.
```

Which sets everything after each instance of "error" as my capture. I'm not quite sure how to set everything BEFORE "Error" as my capture.

Here's an interactive example of what I'm working with: https://regex101.com/r/OWDrVn/2

Any tips?

Comment: Try `(?m)^.+?(?=>[ \t]+Error)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capturing group from the start of the string and capture until the first occurrence of a space and Error followed by a space.

```
(?m)^(?<servername>.+?) Error
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hneDFw/1)

Comment: I freakin knew it had something to do with "^" I just couldn't figure it out.

Thank you. I'll mark as the answer as soon as I'm able (There's a cool down between question and answer it seems). 

Thank you kindly for being so prompt.